# How to properly mock an overloaded Typescript function using Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to mock a single function on an instance using Typescript and Jest. Then instance is an `OAuth2Client` from Google's Auth Library. Here is my module under test:

**sample.ts**

```
import {OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";

export async function accessToken(): Promise<string | undefined> {
    const client: OAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
        "clientId", "clientSecret", "https://redirect.com"
    );
    const response = await client.getToken("code");
    return response?.tokens.access_token;
}
```

For the test, I'd like to return a fixed response from the `getToken` call. What makes this a bit more complicated, is that `getToken` is overloaded and that the `google-auth-library` is Typescript.

```
getToken(code: string): Promise<GetTokenResponse>;
getToken(options: GetTokenOptions): Promise<GetTokenResponse>;
getToken(code: string, callback: GetTokenCallback): void;
getToken(options: GetTokenOptions, callback: GetTokenCallback): void;
```

This is my test:

**sample.test.ts**

```
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';
import {accessToken} from "./sample";
import {GetTokenResponse} from "google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client";

type GetTokenByCode = (code: string) => Promise<GetTokenResponse>

const oAuth2Client = jest.spyOn(OAuth2Client.prototype, 'getToken') as unknown as jest.MockedFunction<GetTokenByCode>;
oAuth2Client.mockImplementation((code: string) => {
    if (code != "code") return Promise.reject("Unexpected code.");

    const response = {
        tokens: {
            refresh_token: `abc${code}`,
            access_token: "def"
        },
        res: null
    }
    return Promise.resolve(response);
});


describe('Sample', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });

    it('can get a token', async () => {
        const token = await accessToken();
        expect(token).toBeDefined();
        expect(oAuth2Client).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

When I run this test, I receive the following error - which indicates that the client is trying the real call.

```
Error: invalid_client

    at Gaxios._request (/Users/foo/dev/token-service/node_modules/gaxios/src/gaxios.ts:158:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at OAuth2Client.getTokenAsync (/Users/foo/dev/token-service/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:124:21)
    at Object.accessToken (/Users/foo/dev/token-service/src/functions/sample.ts:7:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/foo/dev/token-service/src/functions/sample.test.ts:29:23)
```

Looking at the file `.. google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js`, it seems that the TS transpiler output a js-function with signature `getToken(codeOrOptions, callback)` - which then calls `getTokenAsync`.

I am a bit lost here, am I mocking the wrong overload with `jest.spy`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is this:

```js
const client: OAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
  "clientId", "clientSecret", "https://redirect.com"
);
```

While what you are actually trying to mock is the `prototype` parent object.

```js
const oAuth2Client = jest.spyOn(OAuth2Client.prototype, 'getToken') as unknown as jest.MockedFunction<GetTokenByCode>;
```

I would try the following:

- Nuke `prototype` off the mock
- See if you can avoid creating instances in the system under test via Dependency Injection

Comment: Ok but even with dependency injection, I would still have the same issue right? Then the test would create the `OAuth2Client` and I would still be trying to mock the `getToken` function. For the time being, I can mock the `accessToken()` function instead - but would be nice to know what the problem is here.